# error in sudo config, need help to fix

Tags: bash, sudo, sudoers

My shell give me this error when trying to do a sudo

> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 30 <<

I did not modify this file...

anyway the 30th line is the very end of the file. 
I paste here the last 3 rows, from 27 to 30

```
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

please help me to understand the problem and fix it.
I am a newbie on linux.

Comment: is there anything in that directory? `ls -la /etc/sudoers.d`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [unix.se]

Comment: Perhaps the file needs a newline at the end?  Run `od -xc` on the file to see if `\n` appears as the last character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 30th line is the last one it might indicate that you have problems in the file somewhere along the way.

The parser has reached the end of the file and is telling you there is an error (might be looking for unclosed brackets of any kind etc).

If you can parse the full file or try to read it and go line by line to figure out where is the error.